# Images doens't display when put inside public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, create-react-app

I have a problem with my images that are put inside my Public folder. It's weird, as when I deployed my app on github pages, everything works just fine, but locally - it doesn't work, why is that?

that is how my project tree looks alike:

[image: 1]

and that's how I relate to the images that are placed inside assets folder inside a public folder:

```
<Link src="./assets/fb-icon.svg" />
<Link src="./assets/yt-icon.svg" />
<Link src="./assets/twitter-icon.svg" />
<Link src="./assets/ig-icon.svg" />
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What bundler do you use? vite? webpack?

Comment: tbh I don't really know, Usually I just use cra and that's all I care about, I did not install any bundlers after that, I guess it could be a cause? I don't see any bundlers in my dependencies or scripts neither...

Comment: okay I see cra uses webpack, but I don't see it in my package.json, shouldn't it be there?

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/ *To reference assets in the public folder, you need to use an environment variable called PUBLIC_URL*

Comment: I understand, but why  everything works fine when I deploy this on github pages?

Comment: Because `PUBLIC_URL` is probably `./` after deployment or the other default